# WordPress RSS feed validation error

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss

I've installed WordPress successfully but experiencing a RSS feed error.

I've tried to edit files within the WordPress like `wp-rss2.php` so as to remove the `?` from the first line but it does not resolve the error and I can't tell what is causing the error.

Here is the URL to my feed: http://www.donaha.sk/feed

How can I resolve this?

Please note: I had *Slovak* defined as language under Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme incorrrectly puts in an XML UTF declaration before the doctype in header.php:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

according to  [[Invalid] Markup Validation of www.donaha.sk/ - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.donaha.sk/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654)

Delete that and see if it fixes your UTF problems.

Comment: Try reuploading your core wordpress files; maybe one got damaged on the initial install. Happens many times, according to the Wordpress forums.

Answer (score 1):

Your feed starts with four (not one, not two, not three, but *four* :-) [UTF-8 Byte Order Marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  Look:

```
C:\temp>od -c index.html.1
0000000 357 273 277 357 273 277 357 273 277 357 273 277   <   ?   x   m
0000020   l       v   e   r   s   i   o   n   =   "   1   .   0   "
```

You need to reduce that one or zero BOMs.

There's a chance that whatever editor you're using isn't showing them to you - try a different editor... I was able to remove them with [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) by loading the file, hitting the <kbd>Del</kbd> key until the leading `<` disappeared, retyping that `<`, and saving the file.  The resulting file then had a single BOM, and Firefox was then happy to load it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are some junk characters in front of the XML declaration.
Try opening the file that generates it in something like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/), put the cursor at the very beginning of the file and hit the back-space button a couple of times.

If you copy the XML source from your feed and paste it into Notepad++, you can see that the first character in the source has an odd dot in front of it. You can also see this in the error message Firefox generates when the feed is opened.

This is what is causing the error. You need to find where it is being printed and remove it, which is most likely at the very top of the PHP script that generates the feed.

Comment: This is the first echo line of that file that tris to print output:  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>'; ?>

Comment: Did you try to open the fine in Notepad++?
Try that, make sure you place the cursor at the very start of the file and press back-space a few times.
Also, go to "Format->Encode in UTF-8 Without BOM" and "Format->Convert to UTF-8 Without BOM".
That should remove any hidden characters in front of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the core WP files was probably an incorrect move.  This was possibly being caused by your theme or a plugin incorrectly sending characters at the wrong time.  A default install of WordPress should cause no validation errors with the feed.

You may want to try undoing your changes to the WordPress core files and deactivate your plugins to see if that fixes it.  Then you can re-enable them one by one to find the one causing the issue.

If the plugins aren't causing it then try activating the default theme and see if it is fixed then.  If it is then it was your theme causing the issue.

Comment: the only plugins running are akismet and add to facebook which imho do not do anything to it

Answer (score 0):

Are you running WP in the root directory, or using one of the configurations to run the index at the root level as an illusion? If the latter, one of your plugins might be foolishly hard-coding a path to a core file that isn't there with your installation. And instead of spitting out data into the feed, it's spitting out nonsense.